# Caching of data in a text file — Better options

Tags: asp.net, caching

I am working on an application at the moment that is using as a caching strategy the reading and writing of data to text files in a read/write directory within the application.

My gut reaction is that this is sooooo wrong.

I am of the opinion that these values should be stored in the ASP.NET Cache or another dedicated in-memory cache such as Redis or something similar.

Can you provide any data to back up my belief that writing to and reading from text files as a form of cache on the webserver is the wrong thing to do? Or provide any data to prove me wrong and show that this is the correct thing to do?

What other options would you provide to implement this caching?

EDIT:

In one example, a complex search is performed based on a keyword. The result from this search is a list of Guids. This is then turned into a concatenated, comma-delimited string, usually less than 100,000 characters. This is then written to a file using that keyword as its name so that other requests using this keyword will not need to perform the complex search. There is an expiry - I think three days or something, but I don't think it needs to (or should) be that long

I would normally use the ASP.NET Server Cache to store this data.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "caching strategy"? What kind of data is being written to files? What is it being used for and what is the expected scope/lifetime?

Answer (score 4):

I can think of four reasons:

1. Web servers are likely to have many concurrent requests. While you can write logic that manages file locking (mutexes, volatile objects), implementing that is a pain and requires abstraction (an interface) if you plan to be able to refactor it in the future--which you will want to do, because eventually the [demand on the filesystem resource will be heavier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80424/why-using-more-threads-makes-it-slower-than-using-less-threads) than what can be addressed in a multithreaded context.
2. Speaking of which, unless you implement paging, you will be reading and writing the entire file every time you access it. That's slow. Even paging is slow compared to an in-memory operation. Compare [what you think you can get out of the disks you're using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics#Data_transfer_rate) with the [Redis benchmarks from New Relic](https://blog.newrelic.com/2015/05/11/redis-performance-metrics/). Feel free to perform your own calculation based on the estimated size of the file and the number of threads waiting to write to it. You will never match an in-memory cache.
3. Moreover, as previously mentioned, asynchronous filesystem operations [have to be managed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O#Forms) while waiting for synchronous I/O operations to complete. Meanwhile, you will not have data consistent with the operations the web application executes unless you make the application wait. The only way I know of to fix that problem is to write to and read from a managed system that's fast enough to keep up with the requests coming in, so that the state of your cache will almost always reflect the latest changes.
4. Finally, since you are talking about a text file, and not a database, you will either be determining your own object notation for key-value pairs, or using some prefabricated format such as JSON or XML. Either way, it only takes one failed operation or one improperly formatted addition to render the entire text file unreadable. Then you either have the option of restoring from backup (assuming you implement version control...) and losing a ton of data, or throwing away the data and starting over. If the data isn't important to you anyway, then there's no reason to use the disk. If the point of keeping things on disk is to keep them around for posterity, you should be using a database. If having a relational database is less important than speed, you can use a NoSQL context such as MongoDB.

In short, by using the filesystem and text, you have to reinvent the wheel more times than anyone who isn't a complete masochist would enjoy.